# How to override css of other components from App

Tags: css, reactjs

I need to make fonts for some of my components bigger when my app is in full screen mode. In my App.jsx I have variable that triggers me adding "fullscreen" class to the root DIV of the whole app. I can go brute force and override it like `* { font-szie: 18px; }` but thats too simple. I want to override certain classes only (like `.some-class * { font-size: 18px; }`). Of course React hash stands in my way so here is question: how do I apply my font size to all components in the app?

Answer (score 1):

If you have hashed classes (i.e some-class-[hash]), you can use CSS selector to deal with it.
Like this:

```
[class^="some-class-"]
```

The above CSS selector will select all classes which start with "some-class-".
You can read more about CSS selectors here: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp

Answer (score 0):

You can use `General Classes` like `Bootstrap` or `Tailwind`, then you should use it in your public folder and use `link`css`

```html
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="..." />
</ head>
```

```css
.text-sm {
    font-size: 1rem !important;
}
```

```js
import hashed_classes from "./file.css";

const Component = () => {
    return (
        <div className={`${hashed_classes.class} text-sm`} />
    )
}
```

Comment: interesting approach but we dont use general css libraries. thank you